# resize2fs with uninterruptible sleep

Tags: linux

I want to thrink `/dev/mapper/centos-home` like this:

```sh
resize2fs /dev/mapper/centos-home 4710G
```

but a day gone..

now the process is like this:

```
top - 18:43:16 up 11 days,  6:34,  1 user,  load average: 1.56, 1.58, 1.59
Tasks:   1 total,   0 running,   1 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 95.8 id,  4.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 13160968+total,   419960 free,  3242176 used, 12794755+buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used. 12753631+avail Mem

   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 18341 root      20   0 1078000 962640   1028 D   0.0  0.7  86:01.05 resize2fs
```

Should I keep waiting for its finishing?

Comment: It might have been useful to use the `-p` flag to `resize2fs` so you'd get some sort of progress indicator.

Comment: wait until more than 48h, It is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To preserve the integrity of the file system, the safe thing to do is to let it finish. And while it runs, find what backups you have of the data in case the worst happens and you need to restore.

Over the years, there have been reports of [days long resize2fs](https://serverfault.com/questions/436224/resize2fs-at-81h-and-counting) and [other failures during resize complicating recovery](https://serverfault.com/questions/501593/how-to-recover-resize2fs-failure). However, ext4 is a stable and repairable file system. Probably there won't be a problem, but are you going to take a chance with your data?

Make a risk assessment based on how valuable the data is to you, your recovery time objective to restoring this volume, and if the last backup restore test was successful.